# Get value passed in per(n) method with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

I'm using the Kaminari gem to paginate an API. I'm creating my collections like this:

```
def index
  @my_models = MyModel.ordered_by_date
                      .page(params[:page])
                      .per(params[:count])
end
```

In the API, I'm putting some pagination links for the clients like this:

```
json.current_page my_models_url(
  page: @my_models.current_page,
  count: @my_models.size
)
if !@my_models.last_page?
  json.next_page my_models_url(
    page: @my_models.next_page,
    count: @my_models.size
  )
end
if !@my_models.first_page?
  json.prev_page my_models_url(
    page: @my_models.prev_page,
    count: @my_models.size
  )
end
```

The problem here is that on the last page, `@my_models.size` does not return the correct result for the number of records per page. For example, if I have `17` records, and the page size is `5` and I go to page `4`, then the count param in the pagination URLs will be `2` where it should be `5`.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to get the value passed in with `.per(n)` for a Kaminari collection? It would be nice to use that instead of this:

```
params[:count] || MyModel.default_per_page
```

Answer (score 2):

Just figured this one out. The method I was look for was `limit_value`

```
MyModel.all.page(4).per(5).limit_value #=> 5
```